# CKEditor5 & Angular2 - Getting exact position of caret on click inside editor to grab data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

In Angular2+, I'm trying to get the exact position of the caret when I click inside a `CKEditor5 Balloon Editor` instance. I will have several instances on the page, each dynamically represented through a `@ViewChildren` and a `QueryList` (each instance is a separate editor).

On a high level, I'm trying to trigger a method when a user clicks inside a Balloon Editor, and it will store all the text before the cursor in a variable, and then store all the text after a cursor in another variable.

i.e. if a user types `Hello world this is a test` and clicks inside the div after the "world", it will store "Hello world" in one variable and "this is a test" in another variable.

Any idea on how to accomplish this? I assume I need to create two instances of `Position` and then somehow feed that into a `Range`, but I have no idea on how to feed the `Position` the correct path.

If anyone has a working method for just a regular old single instance of CKEditor 5, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: To get the first position of the selection (non-collapsed selection has two positions) you can use [`getFirstPosition()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_selection-Selection.html#getFirstPosition). But I'm not sure what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I see that someone edited your question, but it's still unclear to me what you want to achieve. You ask both about retrieving the selection position and setting it. If you could write in points what you want to do it will be easier to answer.

Comment: @Reinmar I edited it to try and be more general and avoid confusion. I originally had the method I used in there but it was confusing to look at if you didnt understand how I am building it with multiple editor instances on the same page. So i figured if I could get the answer on how to accomplish what I want on one editor, I could apply it. 

I am essentially trying to fire off a method when a user clicks inside an editor div that will store all the markup text before the cursor position in one variable and all the markup text after the cursor in another variable. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Now it's perfect :) I'll work on an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full solution will look like this:

```
const pos = editor.document.selection.getFirstPosition();

// If you want to get the text up to the root's boundary:
// const posStart = Position.createAt( pos.root );
// const posEnd = Position.createAt( pos.root, 'end' );

// If you want to get the text up to the current element's boundary:
const posStart = Position.createAt( pos.parent );
const posEnd = Position.createAt( pos.parent, 'end' );

const rangeBefore = new Range( posStart, pos );
const rangeAfter = new Range( pos, posEnd );

let textBefore = '';
let textAfter = '';

// Range is iterable and uses TreeWalker to return all items in the range.
// value is of type TreeWalkerValue.
for ( const value of rangeBefore ) {
    if ( value.item.is( 'textProxy' ) ) {
        textBefore += value.item.data;
    }
}
for ( const value of rangeAfter ) {
    if ( value.item.is( 'textProxy' ) ) {
        textAfter += value.item.data;
    }
}

console.log( textBefore );
console.log( textAfter );
```

You use here the [`TreeWalker`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_treewalker-TreeWalker.html) to get all items in a range and stringify text proxies which you find there.

Please note that you get [`TextProxy`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_textproxy-TextProxy.html)s instead of normal [`Text`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_text-Text.html) nodes because the tree walker may need to return a part of a text node (if the range ends in the middle of that text node).

---

**EDIT:** To stringify the content to the data format, (so – including HTML markup, not just text), you need to use a bit different methods:

```
function doStuff( editor ) {
    const pos = editor.document.selection.getFirstPosition();

    const posStart = Position.createAt( pos.root );
    const posEnd = Position.createAt( pos.root, 'end' );

    const rangeBefore = new Range( posStart, pos );
    const rangeAfter = new Range( pos, posEnd );

    const fragBefore = editor.data.getSelectedContent( new Selection( [ rangeBefore ] ) );
    const fragAfter = editor.data.getSelectedContent( new Selection( [ rangeAfter ] ) );

    console.log( editor.data.stringify( fragBefore ) );
    console.log( editor.data.stringify( fragAfter ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Reinmar, I can see how the Positions and Ranges are created. I can log them and they're accurate, which is awesome. Two things though - the string variables are logging as empty still, and it turns out the `for...in` loops aren't firing off, and I'm wondering if it's because they somehow are not iterable? Can't seem to get them to work.

Second, and naturally I'd need to see the output, but how is the markup text being stored? Ideally (and this is ideal), I would need the text variables to store with their markup including asteriks, underlines, etc in the string.

Comment: The high level idea is that I will take the string of markup text after the cursor, and set that data into the next instance of a CKeditor on the page using `setData` I believe.

Comment: Ouch. That's more work. I'll extend my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it. Can't seem to get those `for...of` loops working either. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: You can't make them work? I copied this code from a sample I did so I'm sure that it worked. Are you sure you're not trying to write this code based on an existing CKEditor 5 build? You will need to build CKEditor 5 from source to make this work. See https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html.

Comment: BTW, we realise that this is inconvenient that one need to build CKE5 from source to be able to write small plugins like this so we're working on exposing more constructors in the `editor.*` properties.

Comment: I was using a build versus source. I switched to source following this guide (minus the `...`) https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-balloon_ballooneditor-BalloonEditor.html#create 

But now the toolbar on the Balloon editor instance does not pop up when text is highlighted. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's a code we use in manual tests and it works just fine. I don't know what might've gone wrong :(. You can start a new question for that perhaps.

Comment: Reinmar, thank you, ill start a new discussion if i cant figure out the source editor issue. Is there any way to edit the answer given to save the text as an HTML string? i can worry about converting to markdown later if i need it. but i want to take the HTML string and set it in another instance via `setData()`. thank you.

Comment: I finally had a moment to update my answer. You'll find there a code which works like partial `getData()`.