# How to get the text from an Insert event in CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to process an insert event from the CKEditor 5.

```
editor.document.on("change", (eventInfo, type, data) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "insert":
    console.log(type, data);
    break;
  }
});
```

When typing in the editor the call back is called. The `data` argument in the event callback looks like approximately like this:

```
{
  range: {
    start: {
      root: { ... },
      path: [0, 14]
    },
    end: {
      root: { ... },
      path: [0, 15]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see a convenient way to figure out what text was actually inserted. I can call `data.range.root.getNodeByPath(data.range.start.path);` which seems to get me the text node that the text was inserted in. Should we then look at the text node's `data` field? Should we assume that the last item in the path is always an offset for the start and end of the range and use that to substring? I think the insert event is also fired for inserting non-text type things (e.g. element). How would we know that this is indeed a text type of an event?

Is there something I am missing, or is there just a different way to do this all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, let me describe how you would do it currently (Jan 2018). Please, keep in mind that CKEditor 5 is now undergoing a big refactoring and things will change. At the end, I will describe how it will look like after we finish this refactoring. You may skip to the later part if you don't mind waiting some more time for the refactoring to come to an end.**

**EDIT:** The `1.0.0-beta.1` was released on 15th of March, so you can jump to the "Since March 2018" section.

### Until March 2018 (up to `1.0.0-alpha.2`)

*(If you need to learn more about some class API or an event, [please check out the docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/).)*

Your best bet would be simply to iterate through the inserted range.

```
let data = '';

for ( const child of data.range.getItems() ) {
    if ( child.is( 'textProxy' ) ) {
        data += child.data;
    }
}
```

Note, that a `TextProxy` instance is always returned when you iterate through the range, even if the whole `Text` node is included in the range.

(You can read more about stringifying a range in [CKEditor5 & Angular2 - Getting exact position of caret on click inside editor to grab data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758418/ckeditor5-angular2-getting-exact-position-of-caret-on-click-inside-editor-to#comment82516256_47758418).)

Keep in mind, that `InsertOperation` may insert multiple nodes of a different kind. Mostly, these are just singular characters or elements, but more nodes can be provided. That's why there is no additional `data.item` or similar property in `data`. There could be `data.items` but those would just be same as `Array.from( data.range.getItems() )`.

#### Doing changes on `Document#change`

You haven't mentioned what you want to do with this information afterwards. Getting the range's content is easy, but if you'd like to somehow react to these changes and change the model, then you need to be careful. When the `change` event is fired, there might be already more changes enqueued. For example:

- more changes can come at once from collaboration service,
- a different feature might have already reacted to the same change and enqueued its changes which might make the model different.

If you know exactly what set of features you will use, you may just stick with what I proposed. Just remember that any change you do on the model should be done in a `Document#enqueueChanges()` block (otherwise, it won't be rendered).

If you would like to have this solution bulletproof, you probably would have to do this:

1. While iterating over `data.range` children, if you found a `TextProxy`, create a `LiveRange` spanning over that node.
2. Then, in a `enqueueChanges()` block, iterate through stored `LiveRange`s and through their children.
3. Do your logic for each found `TextProxy` instance.
4. Remember to `destroy()` all the `LiveRange`s afterwards.

As you can see this seems unnecessarily complicated. There are some drawbacks of providing an open and flexible framework, like CKE5, and having in mind all the edge cases is one of them. However it is true, that it could be simpler, that's why we started refactoring in the first place.

### Since March 2018 (starting from `1.0.0-beta.1`)

The big change coming in 1.0.0-beta.1 will be the introduction of the `model.Differ` class, revamped events structure and a new API for big part of the model.

First of all, `Document#event:change` will be fired after all `enqueueChange` blocks have finished. This means that you won't have to be worried whether another change won't mess up with the change that you are reacting to in your callback.

Also, `engine.Document#registerPostFixer()` method will be added and you will be able to use it to register callbacks. `change` event still will be available, but there will be slight differences between `change` event and `registerPostFixer` (we will cover them in a guide and docs).

Second, you will have access to a `model.Differ` instance, which will store a diff between the model state before the first change and the model state at the moment when you want to react to the changes. You will iterate through all diff items and check what exactly and where has changed.

Other than that, a lot of other changes will be conducted in the refactoring and below code snippet will also reflect them. So, in the new world, it will look like this:

```
editor.document.registerPostFixer( writer => {
    const changes = editor.document.differ.getChanges();

    for ( const entry of changes ) {
        if ( entry.type == 'insert' && entry.name == '$text' ) {
            // Use `writer` to do your logic here.
            // `entry` also contains `length` and `position` properties.
        }
    }
} );
```

In terms of code, it might be a bit more of it than in the first snippet, but:

1. The first snippet was incomplete.
2. There are a lot fewer edge cases to think about in the new approach.
3. The new approach is easier to grasp - you have all the changes available after they are all done, instead of reacting to a change when other changes are queued and may mess up with the model.

The `writer` is an object that will be used to do changes on the model (instead of `Document#batch` API). It will have methods like `insertText()`, `insertElement()`, `remove()`, etc.

You can check `model.Differ` API and tests already as they are already available on [`master` branch](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine). (The internal code will change, but API will stay as it is.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

@Szymon Cofalik's answer went into a direction "How to apply some changes based on a change listener". This made it far more complex than what's needed to get the text from the `Document#change` event, which boils down to the following snippet:

```
let data = '';

for ( const child of data.range.getChildren() ) {
    if ( child.is( 'textProxy' ) ) {
        data += child.data;
    }
}
```

However, reacting to a change is a tricky task and, therefore, make sure to read Szymon's insightful answer if you plan to do so.

Comment: It seems like in the version of the API 1.0.0-alpha.2, I have the method getItems() instead of getChildren().